# SwiftUI warning: `Attempting -[UIContextMenuInteraction dismissMenu], when not in an active state`

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

Using `Xcode 12 beta (12A6159)` on `macOS Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101)` when I press "Back" button in NavigationView, navigating back from a pushed View, I see this warning in the console.

> [UIContextMenuInteraction] Attempting -[UIContextMenuInteraction
> dismissMenu], when not in an active state. This is a client error most
> often caused by calling dismiss more than once during a given
> lifecycle. (<_UIVariableGestureContextMenuInteraction:
> 0x6000037689a0>)

I did not get this warning on Xcode 11.5.

The code is dead simple:

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: gameScreen) {
            Text("Start game")
        }
    }
}
```

After having navigated to `gameScreen` and then pressing the "Back" button in the NavigationBar I see the logged warning in the console.

I have not upgraded to any of the new SwiftUI stuff like `App` or `SceneBuilder` etc...

Comment: Just because something is in beta doesn't mean one - at least not me and 2 others - are curious as to why I get this message. Might be an indicator that I ought to change the code somehow

Comment: When running under Xcode 12 beta, but using iPhone SE - 2nd gen - 13.5 simulator - the error does not show up and code works as expected. So, it looks to be a bug in iOS 14 or the simulator.

Comment: 1/ FYI, this isn't *just* a SwiftUI warning - my UIKit console shows the exact same thing. Running Xcode 12, iPadOS 14 (actual device), using a UIButton menu. Only happens when I try displaying a `PHPicker` from via a `UIAction` - and it executes properly.

Comment: 2/ I don't know if you actively participated in the beat cycle last year, but (1) they tend to release new betas every 2 weeks, (2) these sort of messages come and go - yes, that means you'll see new ones appear in beta 2 - and (3) last year they basically broke most everything with SwiftUI in beta 4. Very painful! Most of all? Remember this is beta 1 - if you see this come... beta 4? Maybe then you'll be able to seek a better explanation beyond "it's a beta".

Comment: @Sajjon Thanks for reporting. I was freaking out that it's a problem in my app. I have filed an issue with Apple.

Comment: I'm using App in Beta 12 and I'm seeing it too.

Comment: I'm seeing one too. I have a custom button inside a NavigationLink

Comment: Got it too... Beta 12

Comment: This still exists in 14.5

Comment: @Sajjon I think this is related to the gameScreen. I think you are using UIContextMenu there. If you can tell us more we can help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by an outdated memory access when trying to call the function **_UIVariableGestureContextMenuInteraction: 0x6000037689a0** so it would be better to update the API or look for other alternatives.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).